# Change mesh but keep dimensions

Tags: python

In the scene, I have 2000 such objects

[image: Screenshot of complicated object]

Because they have so many faces, I want to replace each with a plane
But their sizes differ, so I traverse their dimensions and give them to the plane, However, the size is still the default size
I searched for questions and added ‘bpy.context.view_layer.update()’，but it didn't solve the problem

The following is my code. Please have a look. Thank you！

```py
import bpy 

col = bpy.data.collections['Collection 2'].objects

mesh = bpy.data.objects['plane'].data

dim = []

for obj in col:

    dim.append(obj.dimensions)

    obj.data = mesh

bpy.context.view_layer.update()  
  
for d  in dim:

    for obj in col:

        obj.dimensions = d
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. For each `dim` vector, you traverse all objects in your collection and set its dimensions to that `dim` vector. This effectively means, that you set all dimensions to the last vector in the list of dimensions:

```py
for obj in col:
    obj.dimensions = dim[-1]
```

You can reason about that by representing a loop as repeated lines of code:

```py
for i in range(4):
    print(i)
```

is an equivalent to

```py
i=0; print(i)
i=1; print(i)
i=2; print(i)
i=3; print(i)
```

So your loop

```py
for d in dim:
    for obj in col:
        obj.dimensions = d
```

is an equivalent to

```py
d=dim[0]
for obj in col:
    obj.dimension = d

d=dim[1]
for obj in col:
    obj.dimension = d

d=dim[2]
for obj in col:
    obj.dimension = d

# ...

d=dim[-1]  # last
for obj in col:
    obj.dimension = d
```

On each step of the outer loop, the inner loop overrides values set in previous steps of the outer loop.

### Solution

Apply scale of the objects, then in the script copy its dimensions, change the mesh and set the dimensions as scale divided by the replacement mesh dimensions (in case of a cube you could just do `o.scale = d/2` since the cube has dimensions 2;2;2)

```py
import bpy

cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
cd = cube.dimensions

for o in bpy.data.collections['col'].objects:
    d = o.dimensions
    o.data = cube.data
    o.scale = d.x/cd.x, d.y/cd.y, d.z/cd.z
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that it's a problem with nested loops. I always copy the same value to the object
Thank you.